# Compute mean on data frame columns for specific rows selected from list elements in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I would like to obtain the mean of a data frame column considering only the rows selected by a list with different elements. My data looks like this:

I have a list of genesets with gene names (`A`,`B`,`C`...) with the following structure:

```
mylist <- list(
  first_set = c("B", "C", "D"),
  second_set = c("A", "C", "E"),
  third_set = c("B", "D", "F")
)
```

I have a data frame of genes from a differential expression analysis in a table with the gene name and some numeric values such as the following:

```
mydataframe <- data.frame(
  name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
  first_value = runif(6),
  second_value = runif(6)
)
```

I want to compute the mean of the first and second value considering only the genes in each geneset detailed in the list, separately. This means that for first value, I'll end up with mean for first_set, mean for second_set and so on, and the same for the second value. In the end I want a list or a data frame such as this one.

```
desired_output <- data.frame(
  set = c("first_set", "second_set", "third_set"),
  first_value_mean_by_list_group = runif(3),
  second_value_mean_by_list_group = runif(3),
)
```

I guess that it can be done with apply or loops but my thought approach is extremely primitive. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you put some real values in your problem, so that we can see what exactly is supposed to be mean'd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using base R

```
l <- lapply(mylist , \(x) lapply(subset(mydataframe ,  mydataframe$name %in% x)[2:3] , mean))

df <- do.call(rbind , l)
```

- output

```
           first_value second_value
first_set  0.5958386   0.307204    
second_set 0.4836385   0.572279    
third_set  0.5559671   0.3666328
```

Comment: Try it now just updated

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1337)

mylist <- list(
  first_set = c("B", "C", "D"),
  second_set = c("A", "C", "E"),
  third_set = c("B", "D", "F")
)

mydataframe <- data.frame(
  name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
  first_value = runif(6),
  second_value = runif(6)
)

mylist |>
  enframe(name = "set") |>
  mutate(
    data = value |> map(~ mydataframe |> filter(name %in% .x)),
    first_value_mean_by_list_group = data |> map_dbl(~ .x$first_value |> mean()),
    second_value_mean_by_list_group = data |> map_dbl(~ .x$second_value |> mean())
  ) |>
  select(-value, -data)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   set        first_value_mean_by_list_group second_value_mean_by_list_group
#>   <chr>                               <dbl>                           <dbl>
#> 1 first_set                           0.364                           0.224
#> 2 second_set                          0.341                           0.724
#> 3 third_set                           0.450                           0.474
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, can you explain how is the inner part of the mutate working, so I can approve the answer? Thank you very much!

Comment: `map` will take the cell from one column and use this value as an argument to a function or formula. The result will be stored in another column in the same row. First, I created a new column with the filtered data, then I used the new column to calculate means in new columns.

Answer (score 1):

```r
mylist <- list(
  first_set = c("B", "C", "D"),
  second_set = c("A", "C", "E"),
  third_set = c("B", "D", "F")
)

mydataframe <- data.frame(
  name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"),
  first_value = runif(6),
  second_value = runif(6)
)

library(tidyverse)
map_df(set_names(mylist, names(mylist)), ~ mydataframe %>% 
      filter(name %in% .x) %>% 
      summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE)), .id = "set")
#>          set first_value second_value
#> 1  first_set   0.2745788    0.7704410
#> 2 second_set   0.5918136    0.8168732
#> 3  third_set   0.1881355    0.5139927
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another base R would be:

```
aggregate(.~ind, merge(mydataframe, stack(mylist), by.x='name', by.y='values')[-1], mean)
         ind first_value second_value
1  first_set   0.2136646    0.6832443
2 second_set   0.3978780    0.5185637
3  third_set   0.1941386    0.6763993
```